# If section has a link inside it, wrap the content of the section in another div

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to use some jQuery to search inside each of my 'section' html tags, and if it finds an 'a href' tag inside that section, to then wrap the entire content of THAT section in another div...

So far, I've managed to get the jQuery to search each section, and check if an a exists, but I can't then get it to only .wrap() a div around the section content that includes a link... here's my code:

It wraps the inViewport div around BOTH sections (even the one without a link in it).

```js
 //This is doing nothing.  If I remove .sibling('h4') so it is:

  $('section').each(function(){
           if($(this).has('a')) {
            $(this).siblings('h4').wrap('<div class="inViewport"></div>');
           }
        });
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <section id="section1" class="cd-section">
           <h4>Some text here, no link!</h4>
        </section>

        <section id="section2" class="cd-section">
           <h4>
             <a href="#">A link is here!</a> So should wrap another diva round 
             it all.
            </h4>
         </section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use jQuery [`.children()`](https://api.jquery.com/children/) combined with [`.wrapAll()`](https://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/) methods :

```js
$('section').each(function() {
  if ($('a', this).length) {
    $(this).children().wrapAll('<div class="inViewport"></div>');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="section1" class="cd-section">
  <h4>Some text here, no link!</h4>
</section>

<section id="section2" class="cd-section">
  <h4>
    <a href="#">A link is here!</a> So should wrap another diva round it all.
  </h4>
</section>
```